# How to force a commit in fossil-scm omitting the inquiry about time skew and empty comments?

Tags: pharo, fossil

I'm making a GUI on pharo/smalltalk for writing structured docs and I'm using fossil as a SCM for the output files ([STON](https://github.com/svenvc/ston/blob/master/ston-paper.md), markdown and HTML) and I would like to commit changes on these files from Pharo without answering any questions about time skew or empty comments. I have seen the flags on the help of fossil, but these questions seems unavoidable. There is any way to force a commit without answer any of these questions?

Comment: you might want to ask that on the #pharo-users mailing list

Comment: @DamienCassou I have done that. My question is more related with how to pass arguments to Fossil to order it not making any question on time skew or empty comments.

Answer (score 1):

Use `fossil commit --allow-empty --allow-older --comment " " --no-warnings`

This should commit without questions at all. But I would suggest using some meaningful comment instead. At least something is good to be displayed in the time-line of the repository. And it is good practice to comment the changes.